# sql server - inserting rank column in SP table-parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

My problem is similar to this one:
[how to maintain order while doing join in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743373/how-to-maintain-order-while-doing-join-in-sql)

Basically I have a table parameter in a stored procedure that contains some IDs in a particular order. I want to use those IDs in an inner join and return results based on the order of the input table-parameter. So, I must find a way to build a new table that contains a rank together with the IDs.

From what I see on similar posts, there is no way to achieve this in SQL, unless I also feed some extra rank column from the outside non-SQL world (inside my table parameter)?

This seems SO alien to me...
Is that really the situation?

**UPDATE:**

(Obviously, I can't use ROW_NUMBER() or RANK() since those require sorting by a column and I only have IDs in my table)

Basically, my input table is in this form:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IdTable] AS TABLE(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

And it is fed as parameter to my SP.

Comment: Have you got an example of table structure, data and what you're desired output is?

Comment: Are you able to amend the stored procedure to output a column for the order? If the stored procedure doesn't order the data in a deterministic way, then there is little point in trying to force your query results to be in the same order!

Comment: @EdB No, the table comes for the outside world, not from SQL. This is the only place I could probably create an order column, but I want to avoid it. Perhaps, your answer below (making the table-type contain an IDENTITY column) can help (I haven't tried this in table-types before). As for the SP, I am planning to make it order by a column (the created order/rank column), just I don't have this column yet.

Comment: See my comment on my answer below; you can trick SQL Server into using ranking functions on unordered results. Whether you should is another matter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried using IDENTITY on a column, but it seems that the DataTable class that I used didn't allow inserting rows with less columns than the number of columns the table had (so that I could not omit the IDENTITY column when inserting data and let it auto-increment).

What I did instead, was providing the rank column values from C# code and order by that column in my SP.

Not the best solution that I could imagine, but at least it works.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `identity` seed enabled column to your input table now, column will be automatically populated with physical order they are inserted into.
2. Use this column to sort after join

Comment: I will definitely try this one! :)

Comment: I have tried doing that now, but it seems that the DataTable class that I used didn't allow inserting rows with less columns than the number of columns the table had (so I could not omit the IDENTITY column and let it auto-increment). What I did instead, was providing the rank column values from C# code.

Comment: Can you show the insert query where you are getting error? (you need to omit the new column from insert), Better way, add this new column at the end

Comment: Yes, I know. But I was using a wrapper class that was generating all the SQL. And I cannot bypass this class. That's why this solution did not work for me. It should be a viable solution for other case though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you are after is a sub-query with a ranking function:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx

If you build your sub-query with a column generated from e.g. `ROW_NUMBER()`, and alias that sub-query and join to it, you can then order your query results by that column.

Comment: If you're not sorting your results, you cannot guarantee what order SQL Server will return them, as it depends on the execution plan that is used to generate them.

Comment: I don't think I can't use ROW_NUMBER() or RANK() on my input table-parameter, since those require sorting by a column. And I only have IDs.

Comment: Apparently, this works : `row_number() over (order by (select 1))`. From here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20232641/add-a-row-number-to-result-set-of-a-sql-query

Comment: This tricks the ORDER BY into using the natural order of the results set (essentially, every row has the same rank) - I'm actually surprised to see that SQL Server allows this, as in most cases the results are going to be non-deterministic.

Comment: I have thought of that, but again, it is not guaranteed that the `order by` is stable (with stable meaning that it would keep the natural/original order): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15522746/is-sql-order-by-clause-guaranteed-to-be-stable-by-standards

Comment: I think this is stable, insofar as it won't reorder your results, so it will number the records in the same order they are returned from your stored procedure. Note that the `ORDER BY` doesn't have to be `SELECT 1`, it can be any constant; other examples use `SELECT NULL`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066819/what-does-order-by-select-null-mean

Comment: OK. I will give this a try if I decide not to use Pravin Deshmukh's answer. :)

Comment: I'll just add (to stress the point) - if your SP returns unordered results, this is NON-DETERMINISTIC - you might get the same order 1000 times, and then have it change because the server looks at the statistics and chooses a different execution plan.

Comment: No, I am planning to sort te SP results with the newly created rank column. Just donno how to create it first.

Comment: It might be helpful if we could see your SP (anonymised if required) to see how it gets its results. Obviously, it is better to order your results and add the ranking column as early as possible, and keep that column in the SP results when you join them to the outer query, then you can keep the order deterministic throughout. Because SQL queries are set-based, there isn't really a concept of row order without an explicit `ORDER BY` at some point!

Answer (score 0):

I think u can use a new table variable in the structure of your input table parameter and a new column for the rank/rownumber (perhaps identity column).
Then u just have to fil lthe table variable like

```
INSERT INTO @tableVar(...) SELECT (...) FROM @inputTableParameter
```

The you can do everything with the new table variable and the rownumber/rank column.